# PDF data stream with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyfpdf

**Context:** My code fetches a set of coordinates from some png documents and later on performs some redaction in certain fields (it uses these coordinates for drawing rectangles in certain areas).

I want my final output to be a pdf with each redacted image as page. I can achieve this with fpdf package with no problem.

However, I intend to send this pdf file as email (base64 encoded) attachment. Is there any way to get the base64 string from fpdf output?

On top of that, can I use image binary string in fpdf image method?

See the redact_pdf method below (I placed some comments there to be more clear)

Code:

```
class Redaction:
def __init__(self,png_image_list,df_coordinates):
    self.png_image_list = png_image_list
    self.df_coordinates = df_coordinates
    
def _redact_images(self):
    redacted_images_bin = []
    for page_num,page_data in enumerate(self.png_image_list):
        im_page = Image.open(io.BytesIO(page_data))
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im_page)
        df_filtered = self.df_coordinates[self.df_coordinates['page_number'] == page_num+1]
        for index, row in df_filtered.iterrows():
            x0 = row['x0'] * im_page.size[0]
            y0 = row['y0'] * im_page.size[1]
            x1 = row['x1'] * im_page.size[0]
            y1 = row['y1'] * im_page.size[1]
            x2 = row['x2'] * im_page.size[0]
            y2 = row['y2'] * im_page.size[1]
            x3 = row['x3'] * im_page.size[0]
            y3 = row['y3'] * im_page.size[1]
            coords = [x0,y0,x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3]
            draw.polygon(coords,outline='blue',fill='yellow')
        redacted_images_bin.append(im_page)
        
    return redacted_images_bin

def redacted_pdf(self):
    redacted_images = self._redact_images()
    pdf = FPDF()
    pdf.set_auto_page_break(0)
    for index,img_redacted in enumerate(redacted_images):
        img_redacted.save(f"image_{index}.png")
        pdf.add_page()
        pdf.image(f"image_{index}.png",w=210,h=297)
        os.remove(f"image_{index}.png") # I would like to avoid file handling!
    pdf.output("doc.pdf","F") # I would like to avoid file handling!
    #return pdf #this is what I want, to return the pdf as base64 or binary
```

Comment: if you save in file then you can read it as `bytes` and use standard module `base64` -ie. `base64.b64encode()`. You may also use standard `io.BytesIO()` to create file in memory and then you don't have to save file on hard drive. The same way you may use `io.BytesIO()` to create file image in memory and use it instead of file on hard drive. Many functions may read/write  `io.BytesIO()` (file-like object) instead of `filename`

Comment: on Stackoverflow you may find questions which show how to use `io.BytesIO`  and `base64` to send image (or other file) from `Flask` to HTML/JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [documentation](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/output/index.html) I found that you can get PDF as string using

```
pdf_string = pdf.output(dest='S')
```

so you can use standard module `base64`

```
import fpdf
import base64

pdf = fpdf.FPDF()

# ... add some elements ...

pdf_string = pdf.output(dest='S')
pdf_bytes  = pdf_string.encode('utf-8')

base64_bytes  = base64.b64encode(pdf_bytes)
base64_string = base64_bytes.decode('utf-8')

print(base64_string)
```

Result:

```
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
```

---

As for `image()`: it needs `filename` (or `url`) and it can't work with `string` or `io.BytesIO()`.

Eventually you may get [source code](https://github.com/reingart/pyfpdf/blob/master/fpdf/fpdf.py#L990) and you can try to change it.

There is even request on GitHub: [Support for StringIO objects as images](https://github.com/reingart/pyfpdf/pull/124)

---

**EDIT:**

I found that there is fork `fpdf2` which can use `pillow.Image` in `image()` - see [fpdf2 Image](https://pyfpdf.github.io/fpdf2/Images.html)

And in [source code](https://github.com/PyFPDF/fpdf2/blob/master/fpdf/fpdf.py#L2677) I found `image()` can also work with `io.BytesIO()`

---

Example code for `fpdf2` (`output()` gives `bytes` instead of `string`)

```
import fpdf
import base64
from PIL import Image
import io

#print(fpdf.__version__)

pdf = fpdf.FPDF()

pdf.add_page()

pdf.image('lenna.png')

pdf.image('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7d/Lenna_%28test_image%29.png')

f = open('lenna.png', 'rb')
pdf.image(f)

f = Image.open('lenna.png')
pdf.image(f)

f = open('lenna.png', 'rb')
b = io.BytesIO()
b.write(f.read())
pdf.image(b)

# save in file
pdf.output('output.pdf')

# get as bytes
pdf_bytes = pdf.output()

#print(pdf_bytes)

base64_bytes  = base64.b64encode(pdf_bytes)
base64_string = base64_bytes.decode('utf-8')

print(base64_string)
```

Wikipedia: [Lenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna) [[image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7d/Lenna_%28test_image%29.png)]

---

Test for writing in `fpdf2`

```
import fpdf   

pdf = fpdf.FPDF()

pdf.add_page()
pdf.image('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7d/Lenna_%28test_image%29.png')

# --- test 1 ---

pdf.output('output-test-1.pdf')

# --- test 2 ---

pdf_bytes = pdf.output()

with open('output-test-2.pdf', 'wb') as f:  # it will close automatically
    f.write(pdf_bytes)

# --- test 2 ---

pdf_bytes = pdf.output()

f = open('output-test-3.pdf', 'wb')
f.write(pdf_bytes)
f.close()  # don't forget to close when you write
```

Comment: For some reason performing this:

pdf_string = pdf.output(dest='S')
pdf_bytes  = pdf_string.encode('utf-8')

Does not return a valid pdf binary (I tried to write it in a pdf file and then opened it and it was not the actual pdf, it was a blank pdf!)

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you get in variables. You could also open PDF in text viewer/editor to see what you get in file. But if it opens it without any errors then it is correct PDF but without content. In first example I don't add any pages/text/images so it create empty PDF.

Comment: BTW: after installing `fpdf2` I don't have access to original `fpdf` (because both use the same names for modules) and I can't test this problem. Besides `fpdf2` seems more useful so I would forget `fpdf`

Comment: I added code which writes PDF using three methods but I tested it only with `fpdf2`

Comment: I will have a look at fpdf2 (I did all my tests with fpdf). Really appreciate your help here. As soon as I test it I will write here what I saw. Thank you!